# How to declare gradle version 5.0 in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I used `task wrapper` when Gradle was 4.x but when I change `gradleVersion` to 5.0 , gradle wrapper states that it can't add a task with the same name. This didn't happen when it was 4.x when I could just change from 4.8 to 4.9 without issues. Does Gradle changed how `task wrapper` works?

Comment: The only clue that I've found is `wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Defining a custom `wrapper` task in your build script has been deprecated since Gradle 4.8 version, see [Gradle 4.8 depreciations](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html#deprecations) (section *Overwriting Gradle's built-in tasks" section*)

Since version 4.8 (and before 5.0) you should have a warning message as below if you still define a custom `wrapper` task:

> $ ./gradlew clean --warning-mode all
>
> > Configure project :
>
> Creating a custom task named 'wrapper' has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0.
>
> You can configure the existing task using the
>   'wrapper { }' syntax or create your custom task under a different
>   name.'.

As announced, the support for custom `wrapper` task has been removed in Gradle 5.0, so you need to use the new way for configuring the Wrapper:

```
// Configuring the wrapper, the old way (gradle < 4.8 )
// see https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:wrapper_generation
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
}

// Configuring the wrapper, the new way (since Gradle 4.8) 
// see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper
wrapper{
    gradleVersion = '5.1'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
}
```

Comment: `gradleVersion = 4.9` should be `gradleVersion = '4.9'`

Comment: Thanks for the neat and tidy answer, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As task wrapper is deprecated since the gradle version 4.5, **wrapper** should be replaced by **task wrapper**

```
// instead of
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.0'
}

// try this
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.0'
}
```