# Gradle composite build `Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.`

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have the following composite build

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name='adhoc'

includeBuild '../my-app'
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

defaultTasks 'run'

task run {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('my-app').task(':run')
}

task checkAll {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('my-app').task(':check')
}
```

../my-app/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app'
```

../my-app/build.gradle

```
 plugins {
     id 'java'
 }

 group "org.sample"
 version "1.0"

 task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = '5.0'
 }
```

When I run `gradle` I get

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':my-app'.
> Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.
```

What is happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Try to rename your `wrapper` task, because  `wrapper` task already exists.

Comment: see the accepted answer on this question, it provides explanation of your issue and how to solve it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521437/how-to-declare-gradle-version-5-0-in-build-gradle/53540265#53540265