# How to fix in android the error "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1"?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated the version of **Android Studio** at the **3.4.1**. 
Immediately the version of **Android Gradle Plugin Version** and **Gradle Version** weren't the last so I have changed with **3.4.1** and **5.1.1** (*File > Project structure > Project*).
Now, I'm trying to create an apk but I have the error "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1".
The project is created with **cordova** and first I have updated cordova at the version **9.0.0**.
I also have noticed that I don't have *Build > Generated Signed Apk* but only *Build > Build Bundle*.

After a long search, I have tried to:
1. change task wrapper with

```
wrapper {gradleVersion = '2.14.1'}
```

2. add google() in

   repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
       }
3. Verify that the link "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip" is correct
4. Verify that there is the function mavenCentral()
5. In *File > Settings > Build, Execution... > Build Tools > Gradle* "Use default gradle wrapper" is checked and "Offline work" not checked

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
    }
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle- 
   5.1.1-all.zip
```

[image]

[image]
What can I do to fix the problem? And what can I do to have the function Generated Signed Apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `google()` maven repo in the `buildscript` block

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // <-- add this
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}
```

It is not related to your issue but for the other dependencies you should add the same repo also in the `allprojects` block

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()// <-- add this. 
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Pay attention to `wrapper` task [with gradle 5.x](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html#deprecations).

Defining a custom `wrapper` or `init` task is deprecated with gradle 4.8 and removed in gradle 5.x. Attempting to replace a built-in task will produce an error similar to the following:

> Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.

To avoid this issue, instead of this:

```
task wrapper(type:Wrapper) {
    //configuration
}
```

Do this:

```
wrapper {
    //configuration
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok, I have added the function google() in buildscript and allprojects but now the error is "Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists.".

Comment: @Giu It is a different issue. It is related to gradle 5.x. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521437/how-to-declare-gradle-version-5-0-in-build-gradle.

Comment: I have modify the code but first I had a problem with "<<" near "task cdvPrintProps" so I have canceled. And now I have a new error: "ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :CordovaLib."

Comment: @GiuThis is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I have found the solution for the last error in this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023068/unable-to-run-ionic-app-after-update-to-android-studio-3-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023068/unable-to-run-ionic-app-after-update-to-android-studio-3-0)